# Multiple Middleware to a route

Tags: laravel

I try to add multiple middleware to a route .

like this :

```
Route::get('/licences_to_confirm' , ['as' => 'licences_to_confirm', 'uses' => 'LicencieController@licenceToValid'])->middleware( 'isFederation' , 'isComite');
```

here my kernel :

```
'isFederation' => \App\Http\Middleware\isFederation::class,
        'isComite' => \App\Http\Middleware\isComite::class,
```

here my isFederation Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if ($user && $user->isFederation())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect(route('403'));
    }
```

here my isComite middleware :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if ($user && $user->isComite())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect(route('403'));
    }
```

but it's doesn't work. someone now the way to add multiple middleware class to a route ? thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What error does it shows?

Comment: Might sound silly but what if you get rid of the leading white space? `->middleware('isFederation', 'isComite')`. Other than that, any error? Any spelling errors? Have you done a `dd()` inside each MW to see if they're being called correctly and some other logic may be the issue?

Comment: i get the non authorized page that i created for the people who dont have acces to the ressource. it's only work if i put only 'isFederation' or 'isComite' but not both in the same time because i get redirect to the error blade page that i made

Comment: Are your middleware conflicting with each other?

Comment: yes ! i guess it only work when i put just one argument

Comment: Try adding those middlewares in Route group  => `Route::group(['middleware' => ['isFederation','isComite']], function(){  Route::get('/licences_to_confirm' , ['as' => 'licences_to_confirm', 'uses' => 'LicencieController@licenceToValid']);  });`

Comment: thanks for your reponse , still working with only one middleware not with both

Comment: Did you added your middleware in `App/Http/Kernel.php` ?

Comment: I don't see how your two middleware are meant to be working together. Surely, if the check fails on the first middleware, it's going to redirect before given the chance to check the second middleware? I think you might need to revise your methods

Comment: in my kernel 'isFederation' => \App\Http\Middleware\isFederation::class, 'isComite' => \App\Http\Middleware\isComite::class,

Comment: i made an update in the post ! you will see the full methods

Comment: I still think it's failing because the first middleware check is firing the redirect, before the other middleware can check anything.

Comment: yes i think so too ! any way to resolve this ?

Comment: Create a different middleware that does the checks in one place, or rethink your logic on what needs checking where

Comment: yes i try this one !

Comment: keep you update !!

Comment: now it's working when i create just one middleware with both conditions like : if ($user && $user->isComite() or $user && $user->isFederation()) ! thanks a lot i help guys !!!!